# Python base 64 decode - prints \n rather than starting a newline

Tags: python, base64

I have 2 python scripts, one to base64 encode a file (this one works OK) and one to decode the file.

```
import base64
read_file = input('Name of file to read:  ')
write_file = input('Name of file to write to:  ')
image = open("%s"% read_file,'rb')
image_read = image.read()
image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)

raw_file = open("rawfile.txt","w")
raw_file.write("%s"% image_64_encode)  #Write the base64 to a seperate text file
raw_file.close()

image_64_decode = base64.decodestring(image_64_encode)
image_result = open('%s'% write_file,'wb')
image_result.write(image_64_decode)
image_result.close()
image.close()
```

That above script runs fine, and successfully writes the new file (decoded) as well as a separate rawfile.txt, which appears as the encoded string. So this half of the process is fine.

I have a second python script to decode rawfile.txt, which I can print the contents of rawfile, but when rawfile has a new line, the python prints

```
somerawfiletext\nmorerawfiletext
```

rather than the desired

```
somerawfiletext
morerawfiletext
```

which causes me to get a base64 padding error, thus am unable to decode.

the second python script:

```
import base64
rawfile = open("rawfile.txt",'r')
for line in rawfile:
    print(line.rstrip())
decoded = base64.decodestring(rawfile)
print(decoded)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could alter the first script to use `b64encode` instead of `encodestring`.  This does not include the newline at all, then you could add it in manually.  Then you will have a file which you can read in using your newline character and decode.  So I'm assuming your file looks like this:

file1.txt:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

Now, you could encode that line by line with a simple loop and stick in a list:

```
data = []
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for lines in f:
        data.append(base64.b64encode(lines))
```

Now write that list to a file:

```
with open('encoded_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for vals in data:
        f.write(vals + '\n')
```

Now to read in that file, decode and print:

```
with open('encoded_file.txt') as f:
    for vals in f.readlines():
        print(base64.decodestring(vals))
```

You could also store the raw vals in a separate list and save to a file using the same method, so in place of the first loop, use:

```
raw_data = []
data_to_encode = []
with open('file1.txt') as f:
for lines in f:
    data_to_encode.append(base64.b64encode(lines))
    raw_data.append(lines)
```

Then you have a list of raw data and encoded data you can use as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out once I'm back home. :)